# Pluralization issue for number of communities in profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, plurals

The profile page display is showing **Communities(1)** in this [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/984181/moodle-learner).

I think it must be **Community(1)**, i.e. using the singular form.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. 'Communities' is short for 'List of communities', and the '(1)' behind it isn't part of a phrase. In English (and IIRC almost all languages), the number always comes before the word it pertains to.

It would be different if it said '1 Communities', then it would qualify as a pluralization bug, but it doesn't.